# Can I combine the multiple column in one column in same table with all data?

Tags: mysql, sql

thanks in advance .

i want to combine in two columns in one column based on the id .

please refer below table. in that table i am expecting sub1, sub2 as sub, Lan1, lan2 as lan, p1,p2 as p, o1,o2 as o. and also need to consider id has two p, p has two o .

here id ,p, 0 only has relationship.

[image: waant to combine multi columns in one columns in same table based on id]

Comment: Use function group_concat

Answer (score 2):

You could use union

```
 select id, name, class, age, `date`, sub1 as sub, lng1 as lng, p1 as p, o1 as o
 from mytable 
 union 
 select id, name, class, age, `date`, sub2, lng2, p2, o2
 from mytable  
 order by id
```

Comment: Thank you for you comments. but here id has two p.  p has two o. so we need to display based on the id and p.        

Id---->p1--->o1  
  ---->p2--->o1
  ---->p1--->o2
  ---->p2--->o2

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to similar to unpivoting your data. I believe a **union all** can get you there.

```
select id, name, class, age, date, sub1 as sub, lang1 as lang, p1 as p
FROM temp
union all
select id, name, class, age, date, sub2 as sub, lang2 as lang, p2 as p
from temp order by id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bc95/3)

Comment: Thank you for you comments. but here id has two p.  p has two o. so we need to display based on the id and p.        

Id---->p1--->o1  
  ---->p2--->o1
  ---->p1--->o2
  ---->p2--->o2   .. please refer the relationship between id,p1,o1 in image